# Angular10 proxy-config.json file is not getting detected on non-local environments

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors, angular10

To resolve the CORS error in Angular 10, I have created a proxyconfig.json file and configured it in the angular.json file. It's working fine in local, but it's not working with the non-local environments. Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Define non-local environments? The proxy is meant to be used for development environments only. So get around this you should send suitable CORS headers or not send them at all depending on where you're hosting your application

Comment: env like CIT, SIT, or UAT. does that mean, it won't throw a CORS error in non-local env if the file/resource is accessible locally using a proxy? there is no header passing atm to access this file.

Comment: I dont know what CIT SIT and UAT means. You cannot use the proxy file outside development environment

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this you need to set proxy server on the same host as FE app, but by default, Angular doesn't support any proxy besides local. Under the hood, Angular uses this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware.

P.S. Wish you to find some other ways to do that as it describes in comments above :)